# hbox scrollbar is not showing

Tags: flex4, adobe

i need to put a horizontal scrollbar in a dynamically created Hbox. im writting the code like this:

```
hbxWallAImg = new HBox();
hbxWallAImg.horizontalScrollPolicy="on";
```

but still the no scrollbar is comming.
i have tried by setStyle also. but it is also not working.

Answer (score 0):

The scroll bar will not be visible unless the content of the box doesn't fit in the box's view port. So just by setting the scroll policy, it won't be displayed, but rather when the element will "know" that in case its content doesn't fit, it should display scroll bars. You also need to add some children and dimensions (with, height) to the HBox.

Without dimensions, it will "stretch" as much as it needs to accommodate the content, so no scroll bars will be visible in this case also.

You can find all the info about view ports and scrolling in Flex 4 here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex4_viewport_scrolling.html

Hope this helps.
Have a good day,
Romi

Comment: im adding many childern, when the children are fitting in it its alright. but when the no of children are more then we can not see the children, in that case i need the scrollbar so that by scrolling we can see the remaining children. i have given the dimension but then also in is not showing.